# Как реализовать оплату в телеграм боте telebot?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, бот

Как реализовать оплату в телеграм боте telebot ? // How to implement payment in the telegram bot telebot?
Ответьте полной программой пж

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Тут форум профессиональной взаимопомощи разработчиков, а не биржа готовых решений. За "готовой программой" вам на сайт к фрилансерам.

Comment: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#payments https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py

Answer (score 0):

Ответ есть на гитхабе в виде примера:

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/payments_example.py

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/815366)